# 3D CSS button with angled corner

Tags: html, css, button

I have attached an image and was wondering if anyone knows how to make the button using CSS and html? I have tried with borders and shadows but cant get the corners correct.

[image: button]

I need them to be a variety of colours (on different backgrounds) which is why I ask. I dont mind doing the different colours or just having them with RGBA values. The button is always just slightly darker than the background.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Where the angled corner is? I just can see the shadow...

Comment: What I mean by angled corner is that this effect cannot be produced with a shadow, unless I'm missing something? If you try it with a shadow it leaves a gap in the corners where the button 'connects' with its shadow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easy way to achieve that is to apply multiple `box-shadow`s:

```
a{
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0,
                #000 2px 2px 0,
                #000 3px 3px 0,
                #000 4px 4px 0,
                #000 5px 5px 0,
                #000 6px 6px 0,
                #000 7px 7px 0,
                #000 8px 8px 0;
}
```

Another way, using `skew` on pseudo-elements:

```
a{       
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    position: relative;   
}

b::before, b::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;               /* half of the shadow width */
    right: -10px;           /* negative shadow width */
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    transform: skewY(45deg);    
}

b::after{
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -10px;          /* negative shadow height */
    left: 5px;              /* half of the shadow height */
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    transform: skewX(45deg);       
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b2YpR/2/

Answer (score 1):

This link will give you what you want :
http://cssdeck.com/labs/fancy-3d-button

```
button {
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(219,87,5,1);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(219,31,5,1), 0px 9px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease;
    transition: all .1s ease;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately the generator doesn't take care of the angular look of the corners on the button. At least i couldn't get it to.